# Export CSV using javascript and aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, export-to-csv

I have to make a downloadable CSV file when click on the HTML button. I have created CSV data in my Javascript when click on the button. My question is how to write the data to a CSV file and make it downloadable. I have tried HTML5 download attribute to download the CSV file in client side. But HTML5 download attribute not supported by Internet Explorer. So I need to know how to pass the CSV data to ASPX and make it downloadable. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code to download a csv from a webpage:

JS function:

```
function downloadCSV(csv_out) {
   var blob = new Blob([csv_out], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
   var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
   var link = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a");
   link.href = url.createObjectURL(blob);
   link.download = "filename.csv";

   var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   event.initEvent("click", true, false);
   link.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: HTML5 download attribute not supported by Internet Explorer. I have tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to have Javascript only solution.
Then you can do following:

```
var looongCSVTEXT = ''
document.location ='data:Application/vnd.ms-excel,' +
        encodeURIComponent(looongCSVTEXT);
```

**UPDATE:**

on your page add

```
<input type='hidden' id='Hidden' runat='server' />
```

then in javascript (setting mechanism might be different, its up to you how you set CSV data to hidden control)

```
$('button').on('click', function(){ $('#Hidden').val(CSVData);});
```

then read the data from hidden control on the server side, [and respond with excel file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878525/asp-net-excel-file-download-on-button-click)
If you do not want to [save it to disk first read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608480/best-way-to-stream-files-in-asp-net)

Comment: I want to pass the CSV data to aspx and do server side file download.

Comment: @user3729660 you mean you want to upload csv file contents you have created in JS to server side and then respond with excel file from server file to user so that it would be downloaded?

Comment: Yes. This what I want.