# Download a DOCX file using ASP.net WEB FORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this download function :

```
    protected void ExportData(string fileName, string fileType, string path)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);


        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = fileType;
        Response.Output.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
```

I use it :

```
    ExportData("infoMandat_" + g.NO_MANDAT + ".docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", g.URL_infoMandat);
```

But the file is always empty OR corrupted...

Probably because i'm reading it with a plain `StreamReader`

The solution proposed in the answer is the function `.Transmit()`, question marked as duplicate is absolutely not the solution to THIS question.

Comment: What's the value of `path`? Is it on the same machine as this code or somewhere else?

Comment: Do you get an exception error while reading the DOCX file? If so, what is the message text of the exception error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Excel file download on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878525/asp-net-excel-file-download-on-button-click)

Comment: What is the value of `URL_infoMandat`?

Comment: @Equalsk Path will point to another server, but for now, on my c:\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `Stream` if the file is already in the website folder. You can use either use [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Please make sure `path` is a correct folder location. For example, `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\samplewebsite\`

```
protected void ExportData(string fileName, string fileType, string path)
{
    Response.ContentType = fileType;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    Response.TransmitFile(Path.Combine(path + fileName));
    Response.End();
}

// Usage
ExportData("infoMandat_" + g.NO_MANDAT + ".docx", 
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
    g.URL_infoMandat);
```

Comment: `TransmitFile()` is what i was looking for, i used `.Output.Write()`  when it was plain text, DOCX files are not plain text... of course. Thanks a lot !